# Reader Writer with a monitor

Tags: c, pthreads, monitor

Im using the pthreads library to try and implement a reader/writer application with a monitor.

I call my thread functions in the main the following way

```
pthread_t *tid;
tid = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*(r + w));
int addr = 0;
//Create r # readers
for (int a = 0; a < r; a++)
{
    pthread_create(&tid[addr], NULL, Reader, (void*)&a);
    addr++;
}
```

and then they complete their function through the following 3 function calls

```
void *Reader(void *pid)
{
    static int *id = (int*)pid;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        beginRead(id);
        endRead();
        #ifdef __unix
            usleep(R);
        #endif
        #ifdef _WIN32
            Sleep(R);
        #endif
    }
    return 0;
}

void beginRead(int *id)
{
    //If writelock or writer_queued then wait(canRead)
    pthread_mutex_lock(&writelock);
    while (writer_queued)
    {
        reader_queued = true;
        pthread_cond_wait(&canRead, &writelock);
        reader_queued = false;
    }
    readers++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&writelock);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&output);
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime(&t);
    fprintf(outputfile, "DB value read =:%d:%d by reader number: %d\n", now-        >tm_sec, (now->tm_sec) / 1000, (int)*id);
    printf("DB value read =:%d:%d by reader number: %d\n", now->tm_sec, (now->tm_sec)/1000, (int)*id);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&output);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&canRead);
}

void endRead()
{
    --readers; // just finished a reader
    if (readers == 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_signal(&canWrite);
    }
}
```

This is supposed to make each thread go into the critical section of the code 10 times(so if there are 2 threads created it would access the critical section 20 times)I get the threads to access the critical section of my code the correct number of times, i just can't get it to print the correct thread ID#

so if i called this function with r=2 and R=200 my output would be:

```
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
```

when it should be something along the lines of

```
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number:1
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
DB value read =:30:0 by reader number: 2
```

depending on the timing of each thread accessing the critical section

Comment: `Reader` is followed by 2 opens and 3 closes. `endRead` has 2 opens and 1 close.

Comment: The code passes ***the same address*** (the address of `a`) to ***each*** thread.

Comment: OT: There Is No Need To Cast `void`-Pointers In C.

Answer (score 0):

The code passes ***the same address*** (the address of `a`) to ***each*** thread.

You want to pass a separate address to each thread.

You can do this for example like this:

```
struct thread_info
{
  pthread_t tid;
  int id;
}

...

  struct thread_info * pti = malloc((r + w) * sizeof *pit);
  size_t addr = 0;

  //Create r # readers
  for (int a = 0; a < r; a++)
  {
    pti[addr]->id = a;
    pthread_create(&pti[addr]->tid, NULL, Reader, &pti[addr]->id);

    addr++;
  }
```

---

Also this line

```
  --readers; // just finished a reader
```

concurrently accesses `readers` unprotected.